# Delete entire line if there is a word in it

Tags: list, c++-cli

I am creating a Windows form program. In a form I insert some data through textboxes, and I write them in a file. Once I press the register button I register a line and so on.
Example:

```
test1|test2|test3...

test4|test5|test6...
```

In another form I type a word in a textbox and if this word is in my file I want to delete that line.
Example: the word is test5, so I will delete all the line where it is. I'll have:

```
test1|test2|test3...
```

Thanks to Medinoc user for this:

WRITE

```
ref class MyClass
{
public:
    String^ cognome;
    String^ nome;
    int voto_diploma;
};

//...

List<MyClass^>^ primo = gcnew List<MyClass^>();

//...

MyClass^ myObj = gcnew MyClass();
myObj->cognome = textBox1->Text;
myObj->nome = textBox2->Text;
myObj->voto_diploma = Convert::ToInt32(textBox35->Text);
primo->Add(myObj);

//...

TextWriter ^tw = gcnew StreamWriter(L"primoAnno.txt", true);
for each(MyClass^ obj in primo)
{
//You can use any character or string as separator,
//as long as it's not supposed to appear in the strings.
//Here, I used pipes.
tw->Write(obj->cognome);
tw->Write(L"|");
tw->Write(obj->nome);
tw->Write(L"|");
tw->WriteLine(obj->voto_diploma);
}
tw->Close();
```

READ

```
MyClass^ ParseMyClass(String^ line)
{
array<String^>^ splitString = line->Split(L'|');
MyClass^ myObj = gcnew MyClass();
myObj->cognome = splitString[0];
myObj->nome = splitString[1];
myObj->voto_diploma = Convert::ToInt32(splitString[2]);
return myObj;
}
```

DELETE

```
TextWriter^ tw = gcnew StreamWriter(L"primoAnno2.txt", true);
TextReader^ tr = gcnew StreamReader(L"primoAnno.txt");
String^ line;
while((line=tr->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
{
MyClass^ obj = ParseMyClass(line);
if(obj->cognome != L"cat")
    tw->WriteLine(line);
}
tr->Close();
tw->Close();
File::Delete(L"primoAnno.txt");
File::Move(L"primoAnno2.txt", L"primoAnno.txt");
```

but the deleting part doesnt work properly. Can you please help me to fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? "doesnt work correctly" is a very vague error description.

Comment: that function should write everything is different from "cat" in another file and then overwrite the original file. the problem is that the function delete all the content. by the way it should be if(obj->cognome!=textBox2->Text)tw->WriteLine(line); as i want to "save" everithig is different from the text in textbox.thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell, the function for deleting only checks 'cognome' so if the word you are trying to match is in fact 'nome' it will not match. Try modifying the delete function like this:

```
if(obj->cognome != L"cat" && obj->nome != L"cat" )
    tw->WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: this works!how can i take the text to compare from a textbox?? i have tried if(obj->cognome!=textBox2->Text)tw->WriteLine(line); but with no results