# Edit file content

Tags: file-io, textbox, c++-cli, editing, overwrite

In Form1 I have 2 TextBoxes(surname and name). When I push the "register" button I write them into a file through TextWriter. Every line contains surname and name, So there are 2 fields per line.

In Form2 I want to edit them by asking a parameter. For example in Form2 I have one TextBox. If the surname I type into the TextBox is equal to one from my file, i want to show surname and name in correct TextBoxes in Form1, and after editing surname or name I want to overwrite previous line in the correct place by pushing the "register" button.

Thanks to user Medinoc I write the file like this:

```
ref class MyClass
{
public:
    String^ cognome;
    String^ nome;
};

//...

List<MyClass^>^ primo = gcnew List<MyClass^>();

//...

MyClass^ myObj = gcnew MyClass();
myObj->cognome = textBox1->Text;
myObj->nome = textBox2->Text;
primo->Add(myObj);

//...

TextWriter ^tw = gcnew StreamWriter(L"primoAnno.txt", true);
for each(MyClass^ obj in primo)
{
    //You can use any character or string as separator,
    //as long as it's not supposed to appear in the strings.
    //Here, I used pipes.
    tw->Write(obj->cognome);
    tw->Write(L"|");
    tw->Write(obj->nome);
}
tw->Close();
```

READ

```
MyClass^ ParseMyClass(String^ line)
{
    array<String^>^ splitString = line->Split(L'|');
    MyClass^ myObj = gcnew MyClass();
    myObj->cognome = splitString[0];
    myObj->nome = splitString[1];
    return myObj;
}
```

Hope I was clear enough. I'm not english.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It's still classic text file editing behavior:

What you need is a function to search for a particular line in the file; and another function to modify a particular line. That one will be similar to [the deleting code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474062/delete-entire-line-if-there-is-a-word-in-it).

Find:

```
MyClass^ FindMyClass(String^ surnameToFind)
{
    MyClass^ found = nullptr;
    TextReader^ tr = gcnew StreamReader(L"primoAnno.txt");
    String^ line;
    while(found == nullptr && (line=tr->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
    {
        MyClass^ obj = ParseMyClass(line);
        if(obj->cognome == surnameToFind)
            found = surnameToFind;
    }
    tr->Close();
}
```

Update:

```
MyClass^ objToUpdate = gcnew MyClass;
objToUpdate->cognome = textBox1->Text;
objToUpdate->nome = textBox2->Text;

TextWriter^ tw = gcnew StreamWriter(L"primoAnno2.txt", true);
TextReader^ tr = gcnew StreamReader(L"primoAnno.txt");
String^ line;
bool updated = false;
while((line=tr->ReadLine()) != nullptr)
{
    MyClass^ obj = ParseMyClass(line);
    if(obj->cognome == objToUpdate->cognome)
    {
        line = objToUpdate->cognome + L"|" + objToUpdate->nome;
        updated = true;
    }
    tw->WriteLine(line);
}
//If the surname was not in the file at all, add it.
if(!updated)
{
    line = objToUpdate->cognome + L"|" + objToUpdate->nome;
    tw->WriteLine(line);
}
tr->Close();
tw->Close();
File::Delete(L"primoAnno.txt");
File::Move(L"primoAnno2.txt", L"primoAnno.txt");
```

Comment: i need to try it.but i m not sure about one thing.from editing form the code should show the previous "cognome" and "nome" in the textboxes of the registration form.i guess this code wont do it.so i ask you how can i manage form1 textboxes from form2?for example //form2.cpp myproject::form1->textBox1->Text=obj->cognome?thanks

Comment: I guess the same way it's done in FileDialog: You expose public properties that are available after the form is closed.